# "CSRF detected" with Omniauth and Google

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra, omniauth

I'm getting this

> OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError at /auth/google/callback
>   csrf_detected | CSRF detected

My code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/json"
require "sinatra/config_file"
require 'omniauth-oauth2'
require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

use Rack::Logger

config_file "config/app_config.yml"
use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: '5fb7w345y3489f523y4h'

configure do
  enable :sessions
end

use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, settings.google[:client_id], settings.google[:secret],
    {
      :scope => "userinfo.profile",
      :access_type => "offline",
      :prompt => "select_account consent",
      :name => "google"
    }
end

get '/list' do
  json get_list
end

get '/' do
  %Q|<a href='/auth/google'>Sign in with Google</a>|
end

get '/auth/:name/callback' do
  @auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  @auth.inspect
end
```

My callback is returning both code and state.

Comment: I just restarted the server and every thing was absolutely fine :P

Comment: config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', domain: 'my_app.com'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the same problem

> (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
>   (google_oauth2)
>   Authentication failure! csrf_detected:
>   OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF
>   detected

Last Omniauth-oauth2 update introduced the "state" param has a mandatory field.

Some people suggest using provider_ignores_state: true but it's a bad idea because it introduces csrf flaw

Guess we'll have to downgrade to previous version to keep google_oauth2 working.

Issue it on https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/58

Comment: A website did this to me. Is there a workaround for me as an user?

Comment: So what's the verison that makes this work?  Also set "provider_ignores_state: true" where?

Comment: As suggested by their GitHub repo `provider_ignores_state` is only for AJAX flows. https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/blob/247eba0b53381a1193edb528e42648885cbc18bf/examples/config.ru#L114-L119

Answer (score 11):

This problem occurs with rails when the domain defined in `/config/initializer/session_store.rb` is different from the origin/redirect_uri defined in the google api console.

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', domain: 'my_app.com'
```

Removing the domain params or using the same domain on both sides fixed the problem.

Comment: Also check that cookies are enabled in the browser, that fixed my CSRF detected error, my /config/initializer/session_store.rb

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_XXX-XXXXX_session'`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Devise with OmniAuth you need to skip the extra omniauth.rb initializer file and simply add config.provider "KEY", "SECRET" inside your initializers/devise.rb and then carry on with your implementation.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, not the other stuff -- I already had domain: :all in the session store config.

Comment: Fixed for us as well...the reason why this fixes it is because if you have the code in both locations, it fires this code from the omniauth gem twice, and the second time, omniauth.state is nil because it was deleted in the first iteration.

        elsif !options.provider_ignores_state && (request.params["state"].to_s.empty? || request.params["state"] != session.delete("omniauth.state"))
          fail!(:csrf_detected, CallbackError.new(:csrf_detected, "CSRF detected"))

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting back and reattempting to log in? I was getting this issue and it was really confusing me, but it was because I was going back to retry. If I typed in the address again, I wouldn't get the issue